# htaccess url rewriting, query parameters are not available in script

Tags: php, url-rewriting, query-string

I am using following rule to rewrite a url in directory style,

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ post.php?pid=$1
```

by using this i am directing `localhost/post.php?pid=3` to `localhost/post/3`

but now I want to pass more parameters in default way  like `?key=value`.

for example `localhost/post/3?comment_id=23`
but this key value pair is not available in script. 
When I do `echo $_GET['comment_id']` it's not echo'ing anything.

How do I get it done.

Comment: You could try removing the `$` from `^post/([0-9+)$` this means ends with, I'm not sure if that will actually work or not but it's a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use QSA (query string append) flag. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ post.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

QSA flag will append pid query parameter while preserving original query string in the URI thus you can do:

```
$_GET['comment_id']
```

and also:

```
$_GET['pid']
```

Comment: that worked, thanks...can you give me any link if you know, where I can learn more about this and other flags.

Comment: @vikasdevde: Use this link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html Also if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.